# Question about linearity of a bijective map

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $f$ be a bijection from $\mathbb{R}$-vector space $\mathbb{R}^n$ to itself such that it takes $0$ to $0$ and it satisfy the condition:

for a fixed basis $v_1, \ldots,v_n$ and for all $a_i$ in $\mathbb{R}$, whenever $v=\sum_i a_i v_i$ then $f(v)=\sum_i a_i f(v_i)$.

Then $f$ is linear map.

Q. I want to know whether above assertion is correct or not. If it is incorrect, under what extra assumption, it will be correct?

Comment: I'd like a bit more clarity on the condition. How large are the sums (are they $n$ terms, some other fixed number of terms, or any size we like)? Also, does this hold for any choice of $a_i$s and $v_i$s, or have we got some fixed choices of $v_i$s/$a_i$s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition, a map on a real vector space $V$ is linear if it satisfies
$$
\forall v_1,v_2\in V\quad \forall \lambda\in\mathbb R\quad f(v_1+\lambda v_2)=f(v_1)+\lambda f(v_2).
$$ 
Of course, from this condition,  your property *follows*:
$$
f\Big(\sum_i a_i  v_i\Big)=\sum_i a_i f(v_i)
$$
for *any finite sum*. So the property you stated is *sufficient* for linearity

Bijectivity is not relevant here.